# How do I cross-reference OpenSCAP benchmarks to the CIS documentation?

Tags: security, benchmark, profile, openscap

I'm using the SCAP WorkBench, and have gone in to customize the CIS profile for RHEL 8.  The benchmark items are clearly titled with things like "Modify the System Login Banner".  The item properties even give the Security Identifier.

But I cannot find an easy way to match up the profile items in WorkBench with the CIS document.  The CIS document I have is called ""CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 Benchmark v1.0.0" and it's a PDF.

We used to  use a home-made script to tighten security.  My goal is to match up our old script to the CIS document, and the WorkBench items, to be sure I have everything covered.

Does anyone know of a cross-reference?  Or a table online somewhere?  (to match up the CIS doc with the WorkBench profile items)

Answer (score 0):

There is a table with cross references that you can use:

https://jenkins.complianceascode.io/view/SCAP%20Security%20Guide/job/scap-security-guide-stats/HTML_20Mapping_20Tables/table-rhel8-cisrefs.html

Comment: Perfect!  I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.